# autogen.sh: You need gtk-doc to build this package

Tags: linux, ubuntu, autotools, autogen

I want to compile [LXDE's libfm](https://github.com/lxde/libfm) from source, but when I run `./autogen.sh`, it fails with this error:

```
You need gtk-doc to build this package.
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

After some experimenting, I figured out which package to install.

It was:

```
sudo apt-get install gtk-doc-tools
```

After that `./autogen.sh` executed successfully and created the `./configure` script. I also needed to run `sudo apt-get build-dep libfm4` which installed other dependencies such as the Vala compiler.